# Implementing backtracking line search algorithm for unconstrained optimization problem

Tags: python, algorithm

I cannot wrap my head around how to implement the backtracking line search algorithm into python. The algorithm itself is:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jevyZ.png)

Another form of the algorithm is:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzJd5.png)

In theory, they are the exact same.

I am trying to implement this in python to solve an unconstrained optimization problem with a given start point. This is my attempt at solving so far:

```
def func(x):  
return # my function with inputs x1,x2

def grad_func(x):
  df1 # derivative with respect to x1
  df2 # derivative with respect to x2
  return np.array([df1, df2])

def backtrack(x, gradient, t, a, b):  
 '''  
   x: the initial values given  
   gradient: the initial gradient direction for the given initial value  
   t: t is initialized at t=1 
   a: alpha value between (0, .5). I set it to .3  
   b: beta value between (0, 1). I set it to .8  
 '''
 return t

# Define the initial point, step size, and alpha/beta constants
x0, t0, alpha, beta = [x1, x2], 1, .3, .8

# Find the gradient of the initial value to determine the initial slope
direction = grad_func(x0)

t = backtrack(x0, direction, t0, alpha, beta)
```

Can anyone provide any guidance for how to best implement the backtracking algorithm? I feel that I have all the information I need, but I just do not understand the implementation in code

Comment: Partial Derivative Rule: `F(xi + dxi, ...) = F(xi, ...) + dxi * dfxi`

Comment: This is calculated in the function 'grad_func'

Comment: are you supposed to solve for change in x1 and x2 or solve for ? what's the inputs ?

Comment: the backtracking line search algorithm is meant to find the optimal step size. Once the step size is found, I will implement a gradient descent algorithm

Comment: by step size you mean `t` value ?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: ok one last question: how do you get the values for Dx1 and Dx2 ?

Comment: If by Dx1 and Dx2 you mean the partial derivatives, they are notated as df1 and df2 within the 'grad_func' function.  If you mean the DeltaX term... well that is also what I was confused about from the algorithm

Comment: no i mean the changes in x1 and x2. Delta X in your photo, you wrote the function for Delta f(x)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not understand that aspect either. x1 and x2 should not change if my understanding of the algorithm is correct. I uploaded another photo of the same algorithm with a different format, which does not include a deltaX term

Comment: but they should, `t` makes no sense if you have no values for Dx1 and Dx2 because the formula states: `F(x1 + t*Dx1, x2 + t*Dx2) < F(x1, x2) + a*t*[dfx1, dfx2] . [Dx1, Dx2]` as you see t is related to all terms which have Dx1 and Dx2 which is the change of x. Ah now it makes sense.. You need to solve first for Dx : [Dx1, Dx2] then compute `t` (according to second picture).

Comment: then it's easy implementing the second formula, it's just while loop.

Comment: Could you provide sample/pseudo code? I know that this is supposed to be a simple algorithm, but I still cannot seem to think through it properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
alpha = 0.3
beta = 0.8

f = lambda x: (x[0]**2 + 3*x[1]*x[0] + 12)
dfx1 = lambda x: (2*x[0] + 3*x[1])
dfx2 = lambda x: (3*x[0])

t = 1
count = 1
x0 = np.array([2,3])
dx0 = np.array([.1, 0.05])


def backtrack(x0, dfx1, dfx2, t, alpha, beta, count):
    while (f(x0) - (f(x0 - t*np.array([dfx1(x0), dfx2(x0)])) + alpha * t * np.dot(np.array([dfx1(x0), dfx2(x0)]), np.array([dfx1(x0), dfx2(x0)])))) < 0:
        t *= beta
        print("""

########################
###   iteration {}   ###
########################
""".format(count))
        print("Inequality: ",  f(x0) - (f(x0 - t*np.array([dfx1(x0), dfx2(x0)])) + alpha * t * np.dot(np.array([dfx1(x0), dfx2(x0)]), np.array([dfx1(x0), dfx2(x0)]))))
        count += 1
    return t

t = backtrack(x0, dfx1, dfx2, t, alpha, beta,count)

print("\nfinal step size :",  t)
```

Output:

```
########################
###   iteration 1   ###
########################

Inequality:  -143.12


########################
###   iteration 2   ###
########################

Inequality:  -73.22880000000006


########################
###   iteration 3   ###
########################

Inequality:  -32.172032000000044


########################
###   iteration 4   ###
########################

Inequality:  -8.834580480000021


########################
###   iteration 5   ###
########################

Inequality:  3.7502844927999845

final step size : 0.32768000000000014
[Finished in 0.257s]
```

Comment: This is an example with the function: `x1^2 + 3x1x2 + 12`

Comment: Ah I see.. Thank you!

Comment: One final question on this. How did you select the dx0 array? what is the logic behind setting it as [.1,.05]?

Comment: @RocketSocks22, no that was just a guess. That's why I asked you how do you solve for it. Anyway I forgot to delete it, with this implementation, I don't use it in my function. I only needed it with the 1st screenshot you sent and that was completely arbitrary. I do optimization myself and this felt like a a good degree of change.

Answer (score 0):

I did that but in matlab, here s the code:

```
syms params 
f = @(params) %your function ;

gradient_f=[diff(f,param1);diff(f,param2);diff(f,param3), ....];
x0 = %first value ;
norm_gradient_zero = %norm of gradient_f(x0));

ov = %value to optimize;
a = %alpha;
b = %beta;

while f(ov, 0)-(f(x0)-ov*b*norm_gradient_zero^2)>0
    ov = a*ov;
end

disp(ov)
```